# Powershell Script To Find/Run Scheduled Task or Create

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to write a PowerShell script to find and run a scheduled task, or if it is not there then to create it. Here is what I have built so far. The else statement works but the first task does not.

```
$taskName = "crebackup"
$taskExists = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -like $taskName}

if($taskExists) {
     Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "crebackup"}

else {
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute “C:\POSNation\SQLBackup\sqlbackup.exe”
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 3am
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'crebackup' -InputObject $Task -User 'usernamehere' -Password 'passwordhere'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the sqlbackup.exe task needed the working directory to start in. This is displayed as "Start in (optional)" when you look at the task using Task Scheduler. To add that, use this for the `$action` variable:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -WorkingDirectory "C:\POSNation\SQLBackup" -Execute "C:\POSNation\SQLBackup\sqlbackup.exe"
```

Also, make sure scripts don't have any smart quotes in them(`“`, `”`). Smart quotes are often automatically generated by word processors and some websites. I replaced the smart quotes in the example above.